# yii2 - how to truncate a table from console

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a console command and I need to truncate a table.

Reading the Class reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#truncateTable()-detail I am not able to understand what files I need to include in order to execute this command.

I am including:

```
use yii\db\Command;
use yii\db\Connection;
```

but not sure which one is correct.

And I have tried to execute:

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->truncateTable('user');
```

which gives me the following error:

> Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: yii\db\Connection::truncateTable()'

and:

```
Yii::$connection->createCommand()->truncateTable('user');
```

which gives me the following error:

> PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Access to undeclared static property: Yii::$connection'

I really don't understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->truncateTable('user')->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, I am just wondering why I don't need to include other files (use yii\base\Component; use yii\di\Instance;)

Comment: how can you understand, reading the documentation, that this is the way how the command has to be executed?

Comment: `$app` it is a application singletone object. In configuration you can see that `components` configuration have `db` component. I't mean that you can access to component in this way: `Yii::$app->db`. And next just use components methods (in your case it's `yii\db\Connection`).

Answer (score 2):

Using yii2 migrate that default function

[yii2 migrate](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-migrations.md)

Step 1. Create a migrate

`yii migrate/create truncate_table_xxx`

Step2. Edit file `xxx_truncate_table_xxx`

Some thing like that

```
class m150101_185401_truncate_table_xxx extends Migration
{
   $this->dropTable('xxx')
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am sure your solution would work but I would like to do this inside another Console controller, that's why I am wondering what files I need to include and how to formulate the same call from another file

Comment: So your solution is Onedev.Link's anwser. `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->truncateTable('user')->execute();`

Comment: thank you, but how can you understand, reading the documentation, that this is the way how the command has to be executed?

Comment: Just read on [http://www.yiiframework.com/] page. but i usually using auto complete that suggest by IDE like phpstorm. You can read source code of framework. Its best way

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good idea using IDE like the one you suggested. I gonna try it today!

Comment: I know this is old, but why doesn't anyone comments about DROP TABLE and TRUNCATE? They're totally different things! DDL vs DML. What if some newbie will gather from this answer that in order to truncate they must drop table?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively one may use:

```
User::deleteAll();
```

assuming `User` is active model class.
This command shows the number of deleted records.

Note, that unlike `truncate` deleting all records will NOT reset autoincrement counter to `1`.

Comment: ...and it can be very slow.